# How to change the name of a group chat with the whatsapp-web.js library in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

How do I change the group name with the specified ID?

the code

```
const groupsid = ['1203631873531*****']
for (const groupid of groupsid) {
    groupid.setSubject(`Seets // []`);
}
```

and output
`TypeError: groupid.setSubject is not a function`